# Loading and fading multiple background images on top of another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load multiple background images on top of another. What is the ideal way to achieve this?

I say background images because I prefer using `background-size: cover` as it scales nicely on all devices. I want this to be responsive, but the images should get positioned on top of the exact buildings that you see in the example.

The images I want to fade in and get overlayed on top are in the same dimensions.

- http://f.cl.ly/items/3p1k0e0j3Y0F2r1N3B00/1.png
- http://f.cl.ly/items/1h3l3b0k3X1s1A272m23/2.png

[My JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/risujoteyi/edit?html,css,output)

```
#hero {
  background: url('https://earthview.withgoogle.com/download/6139.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I also thought about using [sprites](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps), but wouldn't the file size get too big for a background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fade in new images, you can't use the same `#hero` div directly because there is no property like background opacity. It needs a new element which will be faded on it's own. With the possibility of stacking backgrounds by separating the `url`s with a comma, only a single element is needed for both overlaying images. I thought using a pseudo element for this was a nice touch :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjqPNd?editors=011)

```
#hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url(//earthview.withgoogle.com/download/6139.jpg) center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#hero:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image:
  url(//f.cl.ly/items/3p1k0e0j3Y0F2r1N3B00/1.png),
  url(//f.cl.ly/items/1h3l3b0k3X1s1A272m23/2.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

#hero.fadein:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

A tiny bit of jQuery was used here to make sure the fading gets applied when the content has loaded :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  $('#hero').addClass('fadein');
});
```

Edit - here's an example with two pseudos and a few buttons that can toggle fading :

[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwPGvR)

Comment: I really like this solution. Thank you. Is there a way you can load those images one by one? Sorry I forgot to include this on my original question. It's something else I was considering. Is it easily doable?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem but each background will then need an element of it's own. If there are maximum two overlaying images a `:before` and `:after` pseudo could be used. With more, you might be better of with 'real' elements that have `position: absolute`. I'll update the answer and add a few buttons so they can be faded in at any time.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So do you mean that if I have more than 2, then basically I can replicate what was done for `#hero` div and then give it a new unique name in HTML/CSS, right? Something like `#hero-2` for example.

Comment: I do like pseudos and you could indeed replicate it but they are a bit limited to handle with JavaScript - you need multiple classes on the parent for them. With three or more images it's probably easiest and clearer to put together with actual sub elements of the `#hero` div. You would then give each one it's own background and just add as many as necessary. Advantage is that they can all be toggled with the same class. And with this more straightforward approach, it's less complicated to target them with the buttons too. Here's an example, hope it helps : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVbPPL.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me try it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, here's a version of that example with a slightly smarter approach still to the `index` of the buttons. They will keep order better wherever you place them, so first one always targets first image for example (even if all buttons are placed inside another parent) : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKPMVe?editors=001.

Answer (score 0):

I had this simple `js script` + `css` for something similar for a project a while ago that I think is what you are looking for. it was something likee this:

**html:**

```
<body>
  <div id="BG"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Your content goes here
  </div>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
body{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

#BG{
  height: auto;
  background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top-beach-hd-wallpaper.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content{
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#F3D026;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
var imgArr = new Array(
    'http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/top-beach-hd-wallpaper.jpg',
    'http://www.hdwallpapersnew.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/awesome-sea-wide-hd-wallpaper-images-full-free.jpg',
    'http://www.hdwallpapersnew.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/beautiful-sea-wide-hd-desktop-background-wallpaper-photos-full-free.jpg'
);

var nextBG = 0;
var BGPath = imgArr[nextBG];

$(document).ready(function(){
  // ### Autoload BG images
  var preloadArr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
    preloadArr[i] = new Image();
    preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
  };

  // ### Random background switcher
  setInterval(BGSwitch, 5000);
});

// BG SWITCH
function BGSwitch(){
  //Set the background
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+BGPath+')');

  //Increment BG
  if(nextBG >= imgArr.length - 1)
    nextBG = 0;
  else
    nextBG++;

  //make bg invisible
  $('#BG').css('opacity', 0);

  //set new bg
  BGPath = imgArr[nextBG];
  $('#BG').css('background-image', 'url('+BGPath+')');

  //hardcode fix the height
  var docH = $(document).height();
  $('#BG').css('height', docH);

  //fade it back in
  $('#BG').fadeTo(1000, 1);
}
```

You can see the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7jp03vwb/)